# How can I use the built-in “command menu” in Discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

So I stumbled upon a
[cool feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUNdf.jpg)
in Discord.
How can I use this “auto-predict” of sorts in my Discord.py bot?

Comment: Slash commands aren't supported by discord.py

Comment: There is a button on the side with the prefix (in this case a slash), @ŁukaszKwieciński

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know its not the answer your looking for but to my knowledge discord.py doesn't support the / "auto-predict". These commands are only for discords in built methods

**Edit**: I have just learnt I have misinformed you, I was browsing a random server and found this:
[image]

You can see that "Steakbot" has added a /preset of its own. I'll look into how to do this

**Edit 2 + Solution**: It turns out in the discord dev settings for the bot under OAuth2 you can check this:

[image]

Here is the official discord documentation for implementing this including a python example:

https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/slash-commands

Comment: how does the search for this go?

Comment: @Tomodachi94 search completed my friend, good luck